# Does a runner lose a click when encountering Enigma with no clicks left?

Tags: android-netrunner

The Corp has [Seidr Laboratories: Destiny Defined](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/13028) ID: „The first time each turn the Runner loses or spends click during a run, you may add 1 card from Archives to the top of R&D“.

A runner performs a run spending her last click and encounters [Enigma](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/25143). Then the first Enigma's subroutine triggers: „The Runner loses click, if able“.

Does the corp add one card from archives to the top of R&D?

Comment: Is the runner *able* to lose a click? By hypothesis, there are no clicks remaining. So the conclusion of the conditional statement of Enigma doesn't happen. No click lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runner can't lose a click if they don't have one left.

Enigma says: "The runner loses [Click], if able".  The "if able" is the key phrase.  Without a click left, the runner cannot lose one, so the corp ability doesn't trigger.

All of the abilities that cause the runner to lose a click (there are 10 of them as of Reign and Reverie) have this "if able" qualifier.